# Frequency hopping of Si4463

Tags: rf, wireless, frequency

I ask a question in [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/31599/how-to-find-a-clear-frequency-when-use-si4463) , but it has been closed, I just want to know how to realize a simple frequency hopping.

I use [RH_RF24](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/31599/how-to-find-a-clear-frequency-when-use-si4463) to control SI4463, and success to send some simple data. But I know maybe there will be disturb . So, I want a way to avoid disturb.

First, whether there is a way that choose a best(clear) frequency in some range after scan all frequency in the range at beginning ? If have, what is the way ? If giving a detail example, it's really best.

Second, is there any simple and reliable way of frequency hopping ?  Because I want use it in my model airplane, I hope it is anti-interference. About frequency hopping, I really know nothing.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Developing a frequency hopping transceiver system from scratch by a relative beginner is just way beyond the scope of this site. I suggest you go and do some googling, understand the principles (there are many) and come back with questions in about 6 months time. I count myself as someone familiar with this sort of design but it would be a large undertaking for me.

Comment: @Andyaka  I never want to know it detail. I just want to choose another frequence when interference .  I think the main question  is how to find a good frequence and a good arithmetic.  And I just commucate from a point to a point , not  network. Maybe, it is because I know nothing ,so I don't know the difficulty. Thanks.

Comment: You need bidirectional RF for frequency hopping - that's the first complication - both ends need to understand "where they are" in the hopping sequence. Just think about how both ends have to decide what frequency to hop to and what this means in terms of a radio infrastructure.

Comment: @Andyaka  I have a idea. In each cycle (about 50ms) ,  measure  RSSI of a random frequence  and save it. For realize this , I need to  calibrate time . Then , if RSSI of now  is bigger than some value , don't hop to other frequence . But if RSSI of now is  too low, hop to the best of saved.  But I don't know how to choose a suitable minimun  interval of hopping to make  it is maximum efficiency for finding good frequence. Seemly , there are some math about probability and optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most rf-modules allow you to measure the strength of the incoming signal. They often call this "receives signal strength indication" (RSSI). Look for that abbreviation in your datasheets.

Comment: I also think I should use RSSI to decision whether move to another frequence . I want , first choose ten frequency. When RSSI is lower than some value, move to next frequence . Or scanning ten frequency ,then , choose the best one .  Whether there is any problem ?

Comment: Measuring RSSI on the used frequency isn't going to help you detecting disturbances. RSSI is just a measurement of raw energy. Suppose a strong, external transmitter starts on the same frequency. You'll get max RSSI but no signal will get through and the rc plane will crash & burn. Similarly, if you get low RSSI because of a poor signal, changing frequency to another channel on the same band isn't going to help. You could however use RSSI while scanning the whole frequency band and detect disturbances that way.

Comment: @Lundin  Thanks very much. Because my English is poor, I don't understand your last word "You could however use RSSI while scanning the whole frequency band and detect disturbances that way."    But as your  above, I think it is said that RSSI is not useful for scanning whole frequency and detecting distrubances. Is it right ?